# Virtual Host vs rewrite for subdomain

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, virtualhost, rewrite, subdomain

Is there a best practice (for performance reasons or otherwise) for choosing between using a Virtual Host or rewrite for pointing a subdomain to a folder in the root directory?

I.e.,

```
www.domain.com -> public_html/domain.com/
sub.domain.com -> public_html/sub.domain.com/
```

The above can be accomplished by setting up two virtual hosts or by using a single virtual host and just having a rewrite set up to point to the correct sub directory.

My question originally concerned Apache, but I would be interested in knowing if there's a best practice for Nginx's Server Block as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use two virtual hosts because rewriting tends to get messy pretty fast.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite the subdomain should be faster because it does not need to go and read the configuration of your virtual host, still , might be miliseconds (unless the apache is not working well), otherwise I think the best is to do it in a virtual host,due you can manage it from a better way and you dont need to wait for refresh.

Comment: Not convinced.  If you do a rewrite in .htaccess that'll be slower.  If you do it in the apache config it still needs to be read and might generate an internal second request - depending on the nature of the redirect.